# How to count words stored in 2-D array (after adding another word)?

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char Words[][20] = {"Dog", "Cat", "Table"};
    char command[20];

    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter command(Add, End): "); 
        /* input should be "Add" , write down a word, then "Add" again, then write down a new word. */
        scanf("%s", &command);

        if (strcmp(command, "Add") == 0)
        {
            int NumberOfWords = sizeof(Words) / sizeof(Words[0]);
            char NewWord[20];
            
            printf("Enter new word: ");
            scanf("%s", &NewWord);
            
            memcpy(Words[NumberOfWords], NewWord, sizeof(Words[NumberOfWords]));
            
            printf("\nTEST- the number of words is: %d\n" , NumberOfWords);
        }
        
    }while (strcmp(command, "End") != 0);
    
    printf("Program has ended!");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, `NumberOfWords` always stays 3 (AKA. the number of words is always 3) , even after supposedly adding value to `Words[3]` (which should make the number of words = 4). And that makes adding more words into the array Words not possible.

How do I fix that?

Comment: By incrementing it?

Comment: @ventsislav tsenov The array char Words[][20] = {"Dog", "Cat", "Table"}; has three elements. So you may not add a new element dynamically to the array. You could initially allocate the array dynamically and then reallocate it using the function realloc.

Comment: The easiest way is to declare `char Words[MAX][20]` where `MAX` is the maximum number of words you want to store

Comment: Anway `int NumberOfWords = sizeof(Words) / sizeof(Words[0]);` gives the number of elements in an array, not the *used* elements, which you have to keep count of yourself.

Comment: `char command[20]; ... scanf("%s", &command);` should generate a warning.  Save time, enable all warnings.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &command);` -> `scanf("%s", command);` -> `scanf` returns a pointer to and `command` is a pointer to a string. I'll leave error checking and buffer overruns for another day - but please look it up!

Answer (score 0):

Well, to do this you need to choose between two options, created a huge array to store all kind of animals that might be added or you use dynamic arrays and memory allocation. In the code below I use memory allocation.

Basically I create a pointer to a pointer of chars, aka an array of strings and allocate space for 3 of them. I proceed to copy the initial string to those positions. After that, at each cyle you have to use realloc to increase the size of the allocated space.

Bear in mind that I am NOT checking for errors in malloc/realloc but you should always do that. Also, another good practice is to free the memory at the end. This code does that.

Edit: Forgot to mention that "scanf("%s", &command);" is no good. This generates a warning because command is already a pointer.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char **words=(char**)malloc(3*sizeof(char*));
char command[20];
int NumberOfWords = 3;


    words[0]=(char*)malloc(sizeof("Dog")+1);
    strcpy(words[0],"Dog");
    words[1]=(char*)malloc(sizeof("Cat")+1);
    strcpy(words[1],"Cat");
    words[2]=(char*)malloc(sizeof("Table")+1);
    strcpy(words[2],"Table");
do
{
    printf("\nEnter command(Add, End): "); 
    /* input should be "Add" , write down a word, then "Add" again, then write down a new word. */
    scanf("%s", command);
    if (strcmp(command, "Add") == 0)
    {
    
    char NewWord[20];
    printf("Enter new word: ");
    scanf("%s", NewWord);
    NumberOfWords++;
    words=realloc(words,sizeof(char*)*NumberOfWords);
    words[NumberOfWords-1]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(NewWord)+1);
    strcpy(words[NumberOfWords-1],NewWord);

    for(int i=0;i<NumberOfWords;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",words[i]);
    }
    printf("\nTEST- the number of words is: %d\n" , NumberOfWords);
    }

}
while (strcmp(command, "End") != 0);

    for(int i=0;i<NumberOfWords;i++)
    {
        free(words[i]);
    }
    free(words);

printf("Program has ended!");



return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc` should NOT have a cast. Please look up the reason why

Comment: Could possibly use `strdup` if available

Comment: @EdHeal it is not a question of should or shouldn't. It is not bad in any ways and helps keeping track of what is happening in the code, especially if another person is going to read it

Comment: It is bad - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the number of words dynamically, you can use `char**` and store as you wish.

In below example (Its a modified version of your code), I am limiting my self to just 5 words , displaying and freeing afterwards.

you can increase `MAX_WORDS`  based on your need.

There are some more correction i have made w.r.t `memcpy` and `scanf` reading.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 5

int main()
{
    //char Words[][20] = {"Dog", "Cat", "Table"};
    char **Words = NULL;//[][20] = {"Dog", "Cat", "Table"};
    char command[20];
    
    int NumberOfWords = 0;
    
    if( ( Words = malloc(MAX_WORDS * sizeof (char*))) == NULL) 
    {
        printf("malloc failed");
        return -1;
    }
    
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter command(Add, End): "); 
        /* input should be "Add" , write down a word, then "Add" again, then write down a new word. */
        if(1 != scanf("%s", command)) {
            printf("scanf error\n");
            //break to free memory in any allocated
            break;
        }

        if (strcmp(command, "Add") == 0)
        {
            //sizeof(Words) / sizeof(Words[0]);
            char NewWord[20];
            
            printf("Enter new word: ");
            
            if(1 != scanf("%s", NewWord)) {
                printf("scanf error\n");
                //break to free memory in any allocated
                break;
            }
            
            if( ( Words[NumberOfWords] = malloc(strlen(NewWord) +1)) == NULL)
            {
                printf("malloc failed for NewWord alloc\n");
                break;
            }
            strcpy(Words[NumberOfWords], NewWord);//, sizeof(Words[NumberOfWords]));
            
            // increase NumberOfWords 
            NumberOfWords += 1;
            printf("\nTEST- the number of words is: %d\n" , NumberOfWords);
            if(MAX_WORDS == NumberOfWords) {
                printf(" max words reached");
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }while (strcmp(command, "End") != 0);
    
    printf("\n words are: ");
    
    for(int i = 0; i< NumberOfWords; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", Words[i]);
        free(Words[i]); 
        Words[i] = NULL;
    }
    
    free(Words); 
    Words = NULL;
    
    printf("Program has ended!");
    return 0;
}
```