# what is wrong if convert to conditional operator

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-operator

I want to convert an "if" to "conditional operator (:?)". I tried to write it but I get an error `expected expression before "for"`.

The original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int n, i, k, a [10], new;
    printf ("n:");
    scanf ("% d", & n);
    printf ("Initial \ n");
    for (i = 0; i <n; i ++)
    {
        a [i] = i;
        printf ("% d. value:% d \ n", i, a [i]);
    }
    printf ("Enter the index value you want to change:");
    scanf ("% d", & k);
    if ((k> = 0) && (k <n))
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i ++)
        {
            if (i == k)
            {
                printf ("What number will you replace with array index% d?:", a [i]);
                scanf ("% d", & new);
                a [i] = new;
            } // if (i == k) end
        } // end of for loop

                        printf ("Last state \ n");
            for (i = 0; i <n; i ++)
            {
                printf ("% d. value:% d \ n", i, a [i]);
            }
    } // end of if statement
    else
        printf ("You did not enter a value within the array boundaries. \ n");
    return 0;
}
```

I want to convert it to conditional form.

I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int n, i, k, a [10], new;
    printf ("n:");
    scanf ("% d", & n);
    printf ("Initial \ n");
    for (i = 0; i <n; i ++)
    {
        a [i] = i;
        printf ("% d. value:% d \ n", i, a [i]);
    }
    printf ("Enter the index value you want to change:");
    scanf ("% d", & k);
    if ((k> = 0) && (k <n))

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i ++)

        {
            (i == k)?printf("What number will you replace with array index% d?:", a [i]), scanf("% d", & new),(a [i] = new): for(i = 0; i < n; i ++), printf("Last state \ n"), printf("% d. value:% d \ n", i, a [i]), printf("You did not enter a value within the boundaries of the array. \ n" );
        }
    return 0;

}
```

I get an  error: `expected expression before "for".` How can I write this?

Comment: Edit the post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483595/how-to-count-words-stored-in-2-d-array-after-adding-another-word/65484123#65484123)

Comment: Do you want to replace value into an array with another value ?

Comment: The `for` loop is a _statement_. You can only have _expression_s in the parts of the conditional operator. Rewriting big if statements like this does not help with readability. Stick with the if statement.

Comment: yes i want to replace value into an array with another value. But i  want to replace it with the value I entered from the keyboard

Comment: Please understand that spaces matter: `\ n` is not the same as `\n`, and `> =` is not the same as `>=`.

Comment: Consult the language grammar.  All three operands of a conditional operator must be *expressions*.  They may not be arbitrary *statements* such as `for`, `while`, etc.

Comment: `?:` is not meant to be a control structure - it is not a replacement for the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

don't use white space here scanf ("% d", & n);try to concatenate % with d and & with n

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
int n, i, index, a[10], value;
printf ("n:");
do
{
    scanf ("%d",&n);
}while(n<1||n>10);

printf ("Initial \ n");
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    a[i]=i;
    printf ("\n%d. value:%d \n", i, a [i]);
}
printf ("Enter the index value you want to change:");
scanf ("%d",&index);
if ((index>=0)&&(index<n))// write like this : >= 
    {
         printf("What number will you replace with array index% d?:",a[index]);
         scanf("%d",&value);
         a[index]=value;
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf ("[%d]", a [i]);
    }

return 0;

}
```

Comment: thank you but don't we have a way to short while printing the last value?

Comment: @BüşraSarıkaya:  last value in the array ?

Comment: don't use if, use conditional operator also :?

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly

Comment: Corner.  `do { scanf ("%d",&n); }while(n<1||n>10);` is a potential infinite loop on end-of-file.  Useful to check return value of `scanf()`.